# Is there a way to find unanswered bounty questions with specific tags?

Tags: support, questions, bounty, search

There are tabs for featured and unanswered questions. Is there a way to combine them?

Comment: See [How to search only unanswered questions with an open bounty ?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/144952/how-to-search-only-unanswered-questions-with-an-open-bounty)

Comment: Or better yet, [Finding Featured Unanswered Posts](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/198397/finding-featured-unanswered-posts), which actually has a working solution.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use the following Stack Snippet to search on Stack Overflow for bountied (featured) questions, in a tag, that have not been answered. I use the boolean `is_answered` from the StackAPI but that follows the SE defintion, meaning no answers with a positive score.

```js
(function () {
  var api = {
    url: 'https://api.stackexchange.com/2.2/',
    endpoint: 'questions/featured',
    params: { 
      site: 'stackoverflow',
      pagesize: 100,
      order: 'desc',
      sort: 'activity',
      tagged: '',
      Filter: '!bAYUP(Wob-TiH(',
      key: 'V8eFZuqvkHflWf8nT6kx7w(('
      }
    };    
    
  function createUrl(ap) {
    var ep = ap.url + ap.endpoint +'?',
     nv = [];
    $.each(ap.params, function (k,v) {
       nv.push(k + '=' + v);
    });
    console.log(ep + nv.join('&'));
    return ep + nv.join('&');
  }
 
  function enableLoad(func) {
    $('#load').show();
    $('#load').one('click', func);
  }
   
  // load a page of featured questions
  function load(page) {
    api.params.page = page;
    api.params.site = 'stackoverflow';
    $('#load').hide();
    $.get(createUrl(api), function (data) {
      var i, 
          list = $('#fav'),
          next;
      for(i = 0; i < data.items.length; i = i +1) {
          // not answered, SE style
          // otherwise use answer_count === 0  
          if (!data.items[i].is_answered)
          {
            list.append(
              $('<div></div>').append(
                $('<img/>')
                .attr('src','//cdn.sstatic.net/Sites/stackoverflow/img/favicon.ico')
                .attr('title','Stack Overflow'),
              $('<a></a>')
                .attr('href', data.items[i].link)
                .attr('title', data.items[i].bounty_amount)
                .html(data.items[i].title)
            ));
          }
      }
      if (data.has_more) {
        next = function () { load(page + 1); };
        if (data.backoff !== undefined) {
          window.setTimeout( function () {
              enableLoad(next);
            }, 
            data.backoff * 1000);  
        } else {
            enableLoad(next);
        }
      } else {
         $('#load').hide(); 
         $('#search').enable();
      }
    });
  }
  
  $('#search').on('click', function () {
      $('#fav').empty();
      api.params.tagged = $('#tag').val();
      load(1);
      $('#search').disable();
    });
}());
```

```css
#onhold div {
  overflow:hidden;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
  white-space:nowrap;
  }

#load {
  padding: 1em;
  text-align: center; 
  cursor: pointer
  }

img {
  height: 1em;
  }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="error" style="display:none">
</div>
<div>
  <label for="tag">Tag (use one!):</label>
  <input id="tag"/>
</div>
<div>
  <button id="search">Search</button>
</div>
<div id="fav">
  
</div>
<div id="load" style="display:none">
 Click to load more ...
</div>
```

Comment: I didn't manage to run code snippet/code, is it working ?

Comment: @user7294900 it is for me, if I enter the PHP tag. Which tag did you use?

Comment: It's ok, I search for a tag without bounty and got no answer, is there a way to search by all my tags?

Comment: Well, you're free to fork it and add a sensible error if no tags appear ;)  It is possible to find the bounties for your tags by first calling https://api.stackexchange.com/docs/tags-on-users and then call the existing  code for each tag found. Something for a rainy weekend day to add.

Comment: Now I have a reason to be happy it's raining

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Custom Question Lists](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/312781/323179), which you can opt in to by going to your profile (not sure how long it will take to be enabled).

You just need to check the "Has bounty" checkbox, check the "No answers" checkbox, and add your tag(s):

> [image]

I'm not sure what happened to "unanswered-because-no-answers-score-over-0", since there's currently no way to do this *at all* with Custom Question Lists.