# How can I find recently awarded bounty questions for a particular tag?

Tags: discussion, bounty, search

Is there a way to find recently (means up to 2 or 3 days) awarded bounty questions for a particular tag?

I found a related post (answer) of @rene, *[Is there a way to find unanswered bounty questions with specific tags?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/266088/is-there-a-way-to-find-unanswered-bounty-questions-with-specific-tags)*, to find unanswered bounty questions with specific tags.

How do I find recently awarded bounty questions for a particular tag?

Comment: That sits in the votes table, votetypeid 9 is awarded, votetypeid =8 is bounty started

Comment: How recently do you want it to be? Up to 7 days?

Comment: @rene Up to 2 or 3 days

Comment: you need sede and that only updates once a week

Comment: @rene I just realized mods has access to a recently-awarded bounty list

Comment: @SamuelLiew is there any way that normal user can find `recently-awarded bounty question`

Comment: No, unfortunately the list is a mod-only page. https://stackoverflow.com/admin/accepted-bounties